# Laptop behind cascaded router can't ping server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

My network is set up thusly:

[image]

DD-WRT is connected via wire to DD-NETGEAR LAN-to-LAN. My problem is the laptop can't talk to the server and vice versa. Both machines can talk to everything else (via ping) on the network. The laptop is running Linux Mint and the server is running Debian Testing.

```
iptables --list
```

shows empty tables on both machines.

I can't figure out if the problem is network-related or some setting within one of the operating systems. If someone could help, I would be much obliged.

Comment: Do you have AP isolation turned on ? Presumably at 192.168.1.2

Comment: No, it's turned off.